# Itereate through json sub lists

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to iterate and generate html using jquery and a json object.

I'm getting the top level list outputing just fine, but the original object has a property that contains a List

```
                $.each(data, function (i, order) {

                    order.OrderId;

                    $.each(subData, function (j, order.WQIs) {  <=== Having problems on the sublist

                        WQIs.ServiceName ;

                    });

                });
```

What is the proper syntax to iterate through the sublist? The above is yielding an error, "expecting '{'"

Comment: Can you post some sample JSON that you are trying to parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to iterate the WQI's in their own $.each statement like...

```
$.each(data, function (i, order) {

                    order.OrderId;

                    $.each(subData, function (j, order) {  <=== Having problems on the sublist
            $.each(order.WQIs, function(k, wqi) {
                            wqi.ServiceName ;
            });

                    });

                });
```

Comment: Thanks! I had something similar before, but it was yielding all WQIs amoung all orders for each order. Thanks a lot

Comment: Also, I'm new here. How do I mark this post as answered?